# Why is $ \cos(x, y) $ given with two arguments in this paper?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

In the paper [Phrase-Based & Neural Unsupervised Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07755.pdf) on page 4 the authors give a probability equation:

$$\Large{ p(t_j|s_i) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{T}\cos(e(t_j), W e(s_i))}}{\sum_ke^{\frac{1}{T}\cos(e(t_k),W e(s_i))}} }$$

Here, twice the authors use $cos$ with two arguments, both at the top and the bottom of the fraction. There is no reference to $\cos$ indicating any other function in the paper. The paper does mention a rotation matrix, which leads me to believe that $\cos$ is used in its classical trigonometric form. I have looked online for instances where this notation is used, but could not find any.

Can someone explain what the double arguments mean in this instance?

Comment: It cites the Conneau article for the result, I would look there for more clarification. It also specifies $W$ is a rotation matrix of some sort, perhaps the intent is to write $e(t_j) \cdot W$, the only way to know for sure is to look at the original paper.

Comment: Could it be a dot product inside the $\cos$ ? I means $\cos(<e(t_j),We(s_i)>)$

Comment: I think it is a scalar product. The parentheses are overloaded, serving both to indicate the product $(v,w)$ and the argument of $\cos$.

Comment: Seems likely to be a dot product, as suggested by zwim. Then you're computing cosine similarity between the embeddings of $t_j$ and $s_i$ (once $s_i$ is moved to the target space), which is a thing a reasonable person might compute.

Comment: Since the two arguments are vectors, the author might refer to the cosine of the angle enclosed between the two vectors. For unit vectors, this cosine is simply the scalar product between these two vectors ...

Comment: I have looked this up in the Conneau article, they state that $\cos$ in this case refers to the cosine similarity function. I am not sure what the proper procedure is for answers in the comments, but I'll be happy to mark as correct whomever formulates this as an answer to the question.

Comment: @zwim Given that you were the first to comment the correct answer, feel free to answer the question so that you can receive the appropriate credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was provided by @zwim in the comments. When we refer to the [Conneau article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04087) cited in the paper, we find that $\cos$ refers to the cosine similarity function, which *can* take two vectors as an input.